# firebase analytics console：customer can see his own data but cannot see others

Tags: firebase, analytics, amazon-iam, firebase-analytics

I created a android app using firebase analytics,i want one brand can only see its own data and cannot see other brands,how i manage the firebase analytics member in the firebase analytics console

Comment: As far as I know, the Firebase Analytics console is meant to be used by the app developers and everyone who is working on the backend of the app. There's no way to expose this Console to the app users/clients.

Comment: i doubt that whether there is a  custom events to be defined which can Distinguish users（some users belong to a,the other belong to b,a can see a's data but cant see  b's data）